# Angular: Use function of another module in HTML / template

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I have the following module:

```
// in module app/util/utils.ts
export function isNullOrUndefined(obj: any) {
  return obj === undefined || obj === null || obj === 'undefined' || obj === '';
}
```

I want to use the function in my component:

```
// in module app/component/component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  template: `
    <span *ngIf="!isNullOrUndefined(value)">Should not be there</span>
`
})
export class Component {
 value = null;
}
```

However, I am getting the following error message when the component is loaded:

```
Component.html:2 ERROR 
TypeError: _co.isNullOrUndefined is not a function
    at Object.View_Component_1._co [as updateDirectives] (Component.html:2)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.es5.js:13065)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12245)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12610)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.es5.js:12568)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12246)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12610)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12542)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12251)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12610)
```

Importing the function like this doesn't help either:

```
import {isNullOrUndefined} from '../util/util';
```

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The scope for template bindings is the compoennt instance and you can **only** use what the component instance provides.

If you add

```
class MyComponent {
  myIsNullOrUndefined = isNullOrUndefined;
```

then you can use

```
 <span *ngIf="!myIsNullOrUndefined(value)">Should not be there</span>
```

Comment: Alright, works! However, this is not really a nice solution isn't it (criticizing Angular not you)..

Comment: AFAIK there were discussions to make this experience better, but I don't know about the status.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a different name BTY, could do `isNullOrUndefined  = isNullOrUndefined`; RHS is valued to be the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly nicer is

```
class MyComponent {
   get isNullOrUndefined() {
     return isNullOrUndefined;
   }
```

Also can be used to make any imported thing visible, eg Enum types.